# Fix bootup on vodafone webbook ON9 or install from usb?

Tags: boot

I am a greenie with Ubuntu and need help please. Its a vodafone webbook ON9 with 512mb Ram and 4GB onboard flash storage. I need to reinstall Ubuntu. Originally there was Ubuntu 10.04 on it. Now when I switch the webbook on I get a black screen with the following words in black: ' No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.  BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell(ash)  Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands  (initramfs) ''. Can you pls tell me what I can do from here? If not, can you please guide me trhough the steps to install Ubuntu from a usb, because this webbook has no cd/dvd drive? I am from south africa and clueless when it comes to ubuntu while no computer store here in my town is willing/capable of helping me. I installed ubuntu 14.04 on the 4gb stick with an linux installer called xboot; this I did in Windows 7 on a pc. Still I cant seem to boot from it. From what I learned online there's switch at the back of the battery which, if flipped to left, allows you to enter bios-mode when I turn webbook on. Even on the upcoming screen starting with ' (?) Ubuntu Installer main Menu' there's no option to boot from stick. Please help???

I havent heard anything from anyone for almost a week now. And I havent stumbled onto a solution yet. I just need to find out EXACTLY how to get this webbook to boot from the USB, because it insists on 'wanting' or looking for a DVD/CD drive? Anybody? Please??

Comment: Please?? Anybody out there?? Admin?? Why the silence??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

This is an arm device (so you need an appropriate version of ubuntu for that architecture. There is a small switch behind the battery which you need to flip with a paper clip very small switch this will change to boot mode and you can go to the boot menu with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>